# How to get all three digit integer if it is stored in character array?

Tags: arrays, character

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

        static char arr[] = {'21','33','43','53'};

        for (int i=0; i <5; i++)
        {
            cout << "value from array is :" << arr[i]<< '\n';

        }


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: result from above program is :

value from array is :1
value from array is :3
value from array is :3
value from array is :3

but I want is :

value from array is :21
value from array is :33
value from array is :43
value from array is :53

Comment: The `char` type only supports a single character, you can't put two characters in a single position in a char array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this declaration of the array:

```
static char arr[][3]= {"21","33","43","53"};
```

Comment: I donot want two dimensional array

Comment: It's more like an array of strings with max size 3. Other choice would be to use std::string for it.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling this program with -Wall you will get the following warning,

> warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

which means when storing '23', '33' ... there was an overflow converting the value to char. This means the value was not converted completely to char when storing it in that type.

To fix this you either can convert all the values to String or use the appropriate value from the ASCII [table](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/single-quote-apostrophe-ascii-code-39.html). Remember a char can just store a single character within it's single quotes.

Comment: while storing array as i have in above code , i didnot get any error.

Comment: It gave only the second element from each charater, that is if '12', i get only 2

Comment: @user3614428 It's not an error. It's a warning. To turn on warnings while compiling, after gcc you need to put -Wall flag, then it will give you complete list of warnings. A program will still compile if you get a warning but it may have something which is according to compiler not safe programming practise. You are getting 2 and not 12 because of the overflow in the conversion to type char.